# getchar_unlocked Vs getchar Vs scanf

Tags: c, оптимизация, сравнение, поток-ввода

В данной теме я хотел бы поднять следующие вопросы:

1) В чем отличие между *getchar_unlocked* и *getchar* ?

2) Почему scanf("%c", ...) работает медленней getchar ?

3) Какую таки функцию следует использовать или какие сферы применения у данных функций?

4) Есть ли способ считывать ввод в linux еще быстрее?

5) Есть ли разница в скорости у данных функций в C99 и C11 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуй, для начала стоит ознакомиться с [man flockfile](https://linux.die.net/man/3/flockfile).

В двух словах могу сказать, что функции, описанные в `stdio` являются [thead_safe](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-safety) и корректно работают в многопоточной (*mutithread*) среде. Для этого с объектом `FILE` связывается *mutex* (объект, который позволяет разделять доступ от разных потоков, путем их блокировки).

1. Стандартный **`getchar()`** при каждом вызове **производит блокировку** (*lock*), дождавшись своей очереди, читает байт и разблокирует `FILE`, позволяя далее работать с ним другому потоку (*thread*). Естественно, это требует определенных накладных расходов.

Если вы уверены, что в процесс чтения никто не вмешается (например, вручную вызвали `flockfile()` или точно знаете, что работаете с данным файлом в *однопоточном* режиме), то вполне можете вызывать **`getchar_unlocked()`**, который **не пытается блокировать** `FILE` и поэтому **работает быстрее**.

2. **`scanf("%c", ...)`** очевидно медленнее, чем **`getchar()`**, поскольку анализирует строку формата перед выборкой байта из буфера файла.
3. Понятно, что использовать надо те функции, которые максимально удобны для решения конкретной задачи (КО -)) (для посимвольного чтения я обычно использую `getchar()`).
4. Возможно наиболее быстрый способ обработки данных в Linux это использование [mmap](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap). Это функция, которая отображает данные файла напрямую в память пользовательского процесса. Однако, поскольку там есть свои нюансы, то во многих случаях для прикладного программирования это "из пушки по воробьям".
   Очень часто переносимой альтернативой будет обычный [read](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read) с большим (возможно, размером с весь файл) буфером.
5. ??? не измерял, думаю разницы нет. Разница в производительности возможна для разных реализаций *libio* (составная часть *libc*).